# How to set Hover color for glyphs in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

There are two ways to add glyphs in Bokeh. I prefer the second way as it gives more flexibility with Hovers and legends. I cannot find the option to set hover color in the second method. Is there a way to do that?

```
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CDSView, IndexFilter
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import curdoc, output_notebook, output_file, export_png    
from bokeh.models import (
  ColumnDataSource, Circle, HoverTool,Grid, TapTool,PanTool, WheelZoomTool, BoxSelectTool,ZoomInTool, ZoomOutTool, CDSView, GroupFilter)

curdoc().clear()
output_notebook()

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[IndexFilter([0, 2, 4])])

#---------------------Method1-----------------------------
tools = ["box_select", "hover", "reset"]
p = figure(plot_height=300, plot_width=300, tools=tools)
p.circle(x="x", y="y", size=10, hover_color="red", source=source)

#---------------------Method2-----------------------------
p_glypg = figure(plot_height=300, plot_width=300, tools="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,zoom_in,zoom_out,save")
circle = Circle(x="x", y="y", size=10)
c = p_glypg.add_glyph(source, circle)
c_hover = HoverTool(renderers=[c], tooltips=[('x', '@x')])
p_glypg.add_tools(c_hover) 

show(gridplot([[p,p_glypg]]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same way as selected/nonselected can be added at the low level, as described in the documentation:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#selected-and-unselected-glyphs

```
circle = Circle(x="x", y="y", size=10)
hover_circle = Circle(x="x", y="y", size=10, fill_color="red")
c = p_glypg.add_glyph(source, circle, hover_glyph=hover_circle)
```